# DateTimeFormatter returning wrong year

Tags: java, datetimeformatter

I use date time formatter to get a date into a string.

```
LocalDate dateDebutMois = "2021-01-01";

DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-YYYY");

String dateToPrint = dateDebutMois.format(dateTimeFormatter);
```

In dateToPrint I get : "01-2020" instead of "01-2021".

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Lower case `yyyy`. http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/MisusedWeekYear

Answer (score -1):

@AndyTurner's answer for the year was spot on.  But your example has problems.  For one you can't assign a String to a `LocalDate`.

Try it like this.

```
String date = "2021-01-01";
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-yyyy");
String s = dateTimeFormatter.format(LocalDate.parse(date));
System.out.println(s);
```

Prints

```
01-2021
```